# Internal path not set in GVim when launched from gvim.desktop

Tags: bash, xfce, path, fish, gvim

shell: bash, fish

terminal: xfce4-terminal

other-applications: xfce4-whiskermenu, tmux

I'm trying to have GVim inherit the full path from bash and/or fish when launching from from xfce-whisker-menu.

From whisker-menu, I have the default paths set inside gvim: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games`

When launched from the terminal, of course I get the full path of the shell.

I tried altering my gvim.desktop to

```
Exec=/bin/bash -c 'gvim -f %F'
```

But that just ends up launching xfce4-terminal and gvim without the full inherited path.

In addition, following this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23641), I changed my `~/.profile` to inherit from fish shell

```
# Paths
if [ -x "/usr/bin/fish" ]; then
  PATH="$(/usr/bin/fish -c 'echo $PATH')" 
else
  # set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
  if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
  fi
  PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin"
fi
```

I tested this script out in bash and apparently `$PATH` isn't persistent after the script ends.
My shell in `~/.vimrc` is set to bash

Comment: I do not see any actual `export` in your `~/.profile`

Comment: `PATH="$(/usr/bin/fish -c 'echo $PATH')"` won't work as in fish, $PATH is a list, so it will print the elements separated with spaces, not colons. You'll want `string join ":" -- $PATH` instead of the echo.

Comment: Ok, @grochmal and @faho, I changed my `~/.profile` to `PATH="$(/usr/bin/fish -c 'string join ':' -- $PATH')"`

and

`export $PATH`

Comment: The `~/.profile` successfully sets the path for bash but GVim still will not inherit the path from bash. In my `~/.local/share/applications/gvim.desktop`, I have `Exec=/bin/bash -c "bash ~/.profile; echo $PATH; gvim -f %F"` and 
`Terminal=true`. So the path is set for the terminal that is launched with gvim but not gvim itself.